# двойная сортировка в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с разными данными включая поле starts(datetime).
Мне нужна такая сортировка что:
если starts > NOW() тогда order by starts ASC
и если starts < NOW() тогда order by starts DESC

На данный момент я пользуюсь тем что в php делаю два запроса и объединяю их.
Может есть какое нибудь решения который позволит сделать в один запрос?
Мои запросы:
 `select * from table where starts > now() order by starts ASC
 select * from table where starts < now() order by starts DESC`
И объединяю две это результаты в php `array_merge($query, $query2)`
В этом случае я не могу систему страниц данных и разбить результат в несколько страниц
Многие тут советуют использовать сортировку с дополнительный полем типа `if(starts > NOW(), 1, -1) AS 'sort'` и в конце `order by sort DESC`
Я уже пробовал такое но я получу плохую сортировку например:

`id | starts
1 | 03,11,2017
2 | 04,11,2017
3 | 02,11,2017
4 | 02,09,2017
5 | 04,09,2017
6 | 03,09,2017`
Обратите внимание на даты, прошедшие даты конечно оказались внизу но они не отсортированы по убыванию. А предстоящие даты не отсортированы по возрастанию

Comment: А какими запросами Вы сейчас пользуетесь? И в чем соль таких манипуляций? Код в студию, в общем.

Comment: @DaemonHK короче один запрос у меня select * from table where starts > now() order by starts ASC . Второй запрос select * from table where starts < now() order by starts DESC . И объединяю две это результаты в php array_merge($query, $query2)

Comment: А почему бы просто не получить все данные и на php проверять и делать все условия? БД слишком тонкая прослойка, чтобы вешать на нее какую-то логику.

Comment: @DaemonHK Там очень много данных. Думаю в php все будет происходить медленнее.

Comment: @DaemonHK "БД тонкая прослойка" ??? Ну если у вас sqlite внутри проекта, то возможно да, а когда вы пользуетесь серьезной промышленной БД то большинство логики с данными в БД отрабатывает в разы быстрее чем на клиенте. Есть множество систем где вообще вся бизнеслогика в БД, а клинский код отвечает только за визуализацию

Comment: @Mike давайте все таки говорить про реалии, MySQL не шибко хорош для логики (думаю, именно он используется автором)

Comment: @DaemonHK тут я соглашусь, но сортировку лучше отдать все таки ему. И уж точно не проверять условия на клиенте и потом в зависимости от них пересортировывать в массивах. Если говорить о скорости работы, то при наличии индекса по полю starts тот вариант, что сейчас у ТС с двумя запросами наиболее оптимален, потому что условие where отрабатывает по индексу, а сортировка вообще не происходит, идет выбор записей в порядке того же индекса. хотя вместо array_merge я бы данные второго запроса просто при чтении клал бы в тот же массив, что бы избежать копирования массивов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY starts > now() /* ASC or DESC */,
         CASE WHEN starts > now() THEN 0 + starts 
                                  ELSE 0 - starts 
         END ASC
```

Comment: Не знаю как это работает, но этот запрос выводил то, что мне нужно. Спасибо

Comment: *Не знаю как это работает* Простое `SELECT starts, now(), starts > NOW(), 0 + starts, 0 - starts FROM ...` объяснит.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from table
 order by if(starts > now(), 1, -1) * to_seconds(starts)
```

Хотя если следовать логике, что сначала должны быть именно те, что больше по возрастанию, а потом остальные по убыванию, то сортировка скорее такая:

```
order by (starts <= now()), if(starts > now(), 1, -1) * to_seconds(starts)
```

Comment: результат вашего запроса тоже похож на тот который я привел в описании

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  starts,
  CASE 
   WHEN starts > NOW() THEN -1 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starts)
   WHEN starts <= NOW() THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starts) END as sort
FROM
  table
ORDER BY sort DESC;
```